# How to Reference Django Models in ReportLab

Tags: python, django, reportlab

I am creating a pdf using ReportLab and I would like to pull an individual field from my Orders model (the field is called 'reference').  I am currently using Orders.objects.all(), but I'm unsure of how to reference that particular field of the model.

What I currently have:

```
def write_pdf_view(request):
    doc = SimpleDocTemplate("/tmp/somefilename.pdf")
    styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
    Story = [Spacer(1,2*inch)]
    style = styles["Normal"]
    orders = Orders.objects.all()
    for i in orders:
       bogustext = ("This is Order number %s.  " %i)
       p = Paragraph(bogustext, style)
       Story.append(p)
       Story.append(Spacer(1,0.2*inch))
    doc.build(Story)

    fs = FileSystemStorage("/tmp")
    with fs.open("somefilename.pdf") as pdf:
        response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="somefilename.pdf"'
        return response

    return response
```

This returns a pdf with the text "This is Order number Orders object" but I instead would like it to read "This is Order number *reference*"

Answer (score 0):

I think you can access it like this

```
bogustext = ("This is Order number %s.  " % i.reference)
```

Answer (score 0):

At your models.py

```
class Order(db.Model):
    ...

    def __str__(self):
        return self.reference
```